# Populating pandas dataframe based on indexes between two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, between

I'm trying to generate a mask for broadcasting into dataframes: a boolean series that indicates whether a given row is between two values. This is easy to do for single logical statement, say the last five elements in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,1))
mask = (df.index.values>4)
df.loc[mask,'column'] = range(0,5)
```

But how does one do the same thing with more intersectional statements? For example, instead of the last five components in the array, can I address rows 2 through 6? Trying to use an AND statement for the mask fails, and I can't use Between on dataframe index values.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use `mask` mainly if duplicated index values.

So if want use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) working only with Series, is possible use [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) or `Series` constructor.

```
mask = df.index.to_series().between(2,6)
#mask = pd.Series(df.index, index=df.index).between(2,6)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

mask = df.index.to_series().between(2,6).values
print (mask)
[False False  True  True  True  True  True False False False]
```

Or chain conditions with `&`:

```
mask = (df.index >= 2) & (df.index <= 6)
print (mask)
[False False  True  True  True  True  True False False False]
```

But maybe better is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if unique monotonic index:

```
df.loc[2:6, 0] = range(5)
print (df)
          0
0  0.642933
1  0.912846
2  0.000000
3  1.000000
4  2.000000
5  3.000000
6  4.000000
7  0.504830
8  0.000422
9  0.029358
```